# Why is QGIS not launching on windows 10 64bits

Tags: qgis, 64bit, windows-10

I've got a problem using QGIS all version that QGIS is not launching on windows 10 64bits.Before i was used QGIS on Windows 8.1 pro 64bits, everything's okay.After upgraded to windows 10 from windows 8.1, i have got a above problem.

Comment: Do you get any error message? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you reinstall?

Comment: Can you Pls confirm whether below mention application is compatible with windows 10. QGIS 2.8 Thanks
Shubham

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162899)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162899)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162899)

Answer (score 3):

Check admin privileges and that you have the actual 64bit install. Most common reason for this failure is trying to install the wrong version by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall it completely, delete the .QGIS folder in Users, reinstall it with express install with OSGEO4W https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

It should do.